# "The" in front of activity nouns

Tags: definite-articles

I'm getting quite lost on the usage of the definitive article "the" in front of activity nouns like "analysis". Which one of the following is correct and why?

> A. Joe Bloggs is responsible for incident data analysis.
>
> B. Joe Bloggs is responsible for the incident data analysis.

**EDIT:**

I find many examples of when the article is used without referring to a specific incident. For instance, below is an extract from a journal article on traffic incidents in Australia.

> Attention is then directed towards **the** incident data analysis from
>   different points of view along with categorising the data into
>   homogenous patterns for data grouping analysis purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point here is whether the *data analysis* being done is specific or general.

> Joe Bloggs is responsible for incident data analysis.

Conveys that Joe Bloggs' job is to do incident data analysis more generally, whilst,

> Joe Bloggs is responsible for **the** incident data analysis.

Would convey that Joe is responsible for the analysis for this specific incident.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: In the example you give it is still relating to a specific analysis, it is relating to the *corresponding* analysis which is specific to the incident

Comment: Still confused. From the context it's clear that the example above doesn't refer to a specific incident, but rather to a collection of incidents.

Comment: I think you might have interpreted it wrong, as I see it, the article is saying "*attention is then directed to the incident's data analysis which includes data for different points of view etc.*". So in the end the **the** shows that it is pointing to a specific analysis.